# Wiki Pages Library Event Receiver(ItemUpdated) doesn't fire when copy past content from Wikipedia

Tags: event-receivers, wiki-pages

I have attached an event receiver to Wiki Pages Library ItemAdded and ItemUpdated events.

The ItemUpdated event fires when I add/create content from OOTB designer view (Insert, Text Format, etc) then check in.But when I copy past content from Wikipedia and check in the ItemUpdated event doesn't fire.

But the contents are saved in the page and version is updated but didn't trigger the ItemUpdated event. Didn't find any errors in ULS.
Following is the page I tried to copy content from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forest

Thanks.

**Update:**

I drilled down to this issue and below is my finding.
I still believe this is something to do with content(Char encoding).

Following is the part of the content that user copy past as the wiki page content.

> Insurance is intended to protect an already existing or growing
>   estate, not to create an estate at the time of death.  Life insurance

it contains some formatting chars.Below is how it shows in word.
[image]
[image]
I have highlighted the char(between death.  Life) that stops the event receiver firing.
When I remove that char from this paragraph event receiver works fine.

Comment: you need to make the title/ any other field in the  wiki page library as a mandatory field and try to trigger the itemupdated. There exists a life cycle for event receivers. it will trigger itemupdated after itemadded and other methods. let us know the result once you do this.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.This is what I tried, I replace content with content from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurricane_Harvey. Then checked-in didn't trigger the ItemUpdated Event, then edit properties and did page checkout and checkin couple of times still didn't trigger the updated event. There is something to do with content because some wiki content works fine.